# Getting data from complex JSON best practice

Tags: json

I have a complex json object returned from http GET call. In the application I don't need all the data that is returned. Say I only need user and an array of subscriptions with some info from each subscription (subscriptionId, productId, plans).

Would it be better to create an interface that corresponds to all data in the json or parse the response and create an object only with data that I need.

I looked at other seemingly similar questions but they address technical issues related to parsing json. I am interested in best practice of extracting partial data.

Here is example json:

```
    {
  "user": {
    "firstName": "string",
    "lastName":  "string"
  },
  "entitlements": {
    "paymentKeys": [],
    "yourAccountRoles": [
      "youraccount_admin"
    ],
    "subscriptionMemberships": [
      {
        "subscription": {
          "subscriptionId": "<string>",
          "productId": "string",
          "country": "string",
          "companyName": "string",
          "status": "ACTIVE",
          "subscriptionParams": {
          },
          "paymentInfo": {},
          "dataLicense": {},
          "plans": [
            {
              "planId": "plan1"
            },
            {
              "planId": "plan2"
            },
            {
              "planId": "plan3"
            }
          ]
        },
        "membershipData": {
          "membershipStatus": "ACTIVE",
          "roles": [],
          "membershipParams": {}
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the practical difference between "create an interface that corresponds to all data in the json" or "parse the response and create an object only with data that I need"? What do you mean by an "interface" in this context? At some point, you're going to have to parse the JSON and get the fields you want. The stage at which you do that is largely depdendent on your application structure and whether you think you might need any of the other data in future. BTW your question is probably off-topic since it's basically asking for an opinion

Comment: Are you having many of those json at once or just one at the time? If the last is currect then I do not see why creating thinner json

Comment: @DavidWinder I have just one json at a time.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks, I think you answered my question. I think the point is whether I will need the other data in the future. So it's probably better to create an interface (like typescript interface) corresponding to all data. Please post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: If you have only one at a time then I think I rather prefer not creating a new json but use the one received - because then you can use existing library without any extra interface. Having bigger json obj is not too much memory if you only have one